# Add hide all series to line chart

Tags: highcharts, linechart

I have a line chart with a number of series elements on it.

The chart does allow me to click each series in the legend to hide it but I would like to add an extra item that when clicked hides all of the series lines from the chart.

Can someone explain how I would achieve this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a button or something you like. follow the example fiddle from highcharts own.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    $button = $('#button');
$button.click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
        $button.html('Show series');
    } else {
        series.show();
        $button.html('Hide series');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case when you hide all of series, you can add extra serie by [addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29) function.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, this appeals to me more but from the looks of things I need to add some series data etc when really all I would care about is just the series link which I could call "clear all" so I went with the button options on my charts.

Comment: So you need to one button which hide all series, and add new serie? or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I just wanted a hide all series button like the example above except that I thought you were demonstrating that this could be done by adding an extra series link. I wouldnt want to add data for this though, just for it to appear with the rest of the series 'on\off' switched as 'Clear All' but not to actually be linked to a series of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.selectDeselect input').click(function() {
if (chart.series[0].visible) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
            chart.series[i].hide();
          }
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
            chart.series[i].show();
          }
}
```

})